# Symfony 4 - How to use assets in javascript?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, runtime, assert

in my Symfony 4 project I have a view that allows me to select a value from a drop-down list.

I want that each time I select one, there is the image associated with the value that is displayed.

Each image is saved as an asset which has been compiled by Webpack yet. So each image has a base name plus a unique identifier, like this:

**image1.5265262.png**

**image2.26598458.png**

So, in my twig file, I've :

```
{{form_row(form.theme, {'attr': {'onchange': 'changeImage(this)'}})}}
<img id="bootswatch"></img>
```

And this javascript :

```
{% block javascripts %}

    <script>
        function changeImage(select)
        {
            var valeur = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
            var assetBaseDir = "{{ asset('build/images/') }}"
            $("#bootswatch").attr("src", assetBaseDir + valeur + '.png');
        }
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks to that, I can get almost the right thing. I get the path that can lead to my images, except that it does not take into account the identifier of the image that was built by webpack-encore.

For example, if `value = "flatly"`, I can get: `/build/images/flatly.png` whereas when webpack compiled it, it ends up with an additional identifier, and its new name: `flatly.029f753f.png`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not write the compiled image names to a data attribute assigned to each `option` tag?

Comment: Mmmh yes good idea. I could generate the asset path directly from the formType ? But how Can I get it in PHP from thé FormBuilder ?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163803/how-to-get-assets-img-url-in-symfony-controller helps for this? Get `\Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages` and call `getUrl` on it with the full asset path (eg. `build/images/image1.png`)

Comment: Yeah it works good  ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I personally removed the versioning from the image name itself, because I would rename new versions anyway and the asset path can easily be provided by a data attribute. If you use just a few images, you could supply each of them with a data attribute:

```
<img id="bootswatch" data-asset-url="{{ asset('build/images/flatly.png') }}">
```

or

```
<img id="bootswatch" data-asset-url="{{ asset('build/images/') }}">
```

when you want to append the name of the image afterwards yourself. This has the benefit, that you don't need to write your JS code directly into a Twig block, which is something I wouldn't recommend, because it's not reusable and JS could be cached as a static file within the browser.

Comment: mmh suddenly if I want to use the second option to add the name of the image myself, how would it go? Because for my case I have a form which contains a select. And when I select a value, I want to change the src attribute of my image tag to display the one that matches

Comment: It depends if it's important to you to have versioning for these images. I, for example, have a map with tons of different icons in multiple icon sizes on it and I simply set the data-asset-url and I can use this one within a var in JS and append just the icon name.
If this isn't possible, you definitely need to attach all the images as different asset urls somehow. One good idea is what Nico Haase suggested or you could attach all of them to the select itself with data-asset-"value", where "value" is the value of the selected option.