# Get access public folder by url Symfony

Tags: api, symfony

Hi I have a symfony api with some images stored in the public/media folder how can i acces this images with a url like http://localhost/public/media/img.png

Answer (score 1):

`public/` is the web root so `http://localhost/media/img.png` should work. More accurately, the URL will be `http://{your_domain_name.your_tld:your_port_no}/media/img.png`. You can use the twig asset function to [render the proper URL in the template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html#referencing-image-files-from-a-template).

```
<img src="{{ asset('media/img.png') }}" alt="ACME logo">
```

This is completely portable (points to the `public/` directory on the current sever).

If you are not using a template and need to get the URL in the controller [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36163803/6127393)